# Java Error beeping

Tags: java, awt, beep

Im working on a Chat client that i didnt write the bulk of the code for. It works fine however when someone sends a message it beeps (system error beep) when using Java 7.
Java 6 and below doesn't have this beep. I cant seem to find whats causing the beep is there any way to find it ?

I dont think its calling beep as i have

```
public class nobeep extends sun.awt.windows.WToolkit {
    @Override
      public void beep() {
          System.out.println("tried to beep");
          new Exception().printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

and then called

```
 System.setProperty("awt.toolkit", "nobeep");
```

in the main method.

Using the method to send a beep doesnt make it beep. Its only when sent normally. Is there a quick way to track down the cause of the beep ?

Edit:

After looking in the bugs database - its confirmed.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7194469

I know it says no work around but is there one (java not c++) or just wait until update 8 ?

Comment: These sentences are quite unclear, I don't know what to make of them: "Using the method to send a beep doesn't make it beep. Its only when sent normally."

Comment: Hi, the sendMessage(message, user, colour) doesnt make it beep. That is the only thing the listener calls. Tested that by just adding a thread to post every 3 seconds. When posting though the textbox (how it would usually work) makes the beep

Comment: `sendMessage` is not a method you mention anywhere in your question. Without code it is not possible to give you meaningful advice.

Comment: As an FYI, the bell character in Java is '\7'.  If your client/server is reading in the bell character you would get a beep.

Comment: The sendMessage() isnt really that important as it can be called with out beeping. The issue is Java <7 = no beep, Java 7 = beep. The server isnt sending \7 confirmed by tcpdump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was converting awt to swing. I cant find a way to over ride what the fix in the bug report was. Its now working fine in either version

Bug report
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7194469

fix
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/awt/jdk/rev/b8a1ff892b33